# suffering with Java Script Yarn dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

In my root folder for my project I have:

- package.json
- yarn.lock

I created a folder some levels deep, like:

```
{root}/lambda/index.js
```

From {root}/lambda/ folder, I installed aws-sdk dependencies using:

```
yarn add aws-sdk
```

I don't understand why, first, I see nothing under {root}/lambda/, only my index.js. I was expecting to see the aws-sdk dependencies. Second, the package.json and yarn.lock has been updated, even if I ran the command from a total different folder.

I'm new with everything: java script, node, yarn. I don't understand how 'index.js' can be executed even if the dependencies are not present in the folder.

Where are all the java script dependencies? In my 'index.js' I have a line:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

Then if I do:

```
node index.js
```

This runs fine, but how though? How does node where to read the dependencies from?

---

Comment: They're in `{root}/node_modules`. The dependencies will be stored on the level where your package is declared (the `package.json` is placed), not individually in each subfolder.  See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders and https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/folders.html

Comment: I will take a look to that doc, thanks. If you can give me a quick explanation though, why yarn updates yarn.lock, even if I ran 'yarn add aws-sdk' from a lower folder? In other words, how does yarn magically know my project root folder? This question also applies for node. How does 'node' command about '{root}/node_modules'?

Comment: Ah, 'If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the file system is reached.'